# How to reduce font size when it does not fit in the textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

Follow my code: (**XAML**)

```
<TextBox
    Text="Texto"
    SelectionBrush="#FF54FF50"
    x:Name="textbox_principal" 
    Margin="10,53,0,0" 
    FontSize="24" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Width="341" 
    Height="285" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    TextChanged="Textbox_principal_TextChanged"
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    CaretBrush="Black" 
    BorderBrush="Black" 
    Foreground="Black" 
    FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Padding="0,5,0,0" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

If the text does not fit, decrease the font, follow my code **C#**:

```
private void Textbox_principal_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   //check if the text is large, then decrease font size
}
```

Any solution on how to adjust the font size in the textbox?
Please I do not want the solution for `textblock`, just the `textbox`.

I want to set default size of `24`, if the text does not fit in the `textbox`, I want to decrease.

**Update:** (Code below works with winforms)

```
private void label1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
    float p = 20;
    Font f = new Font(((Label)sender).Font.Name, p);
    SizeF s = g.MeasureString(((Label)sender).Text, f);

    while (s.Width >= ((Label)sender).Width - 20)
    {
        p = p - 0.1f;
        f = new Font(((Label)sender).Font.Name, p);
        s = g.MeasureString(((Label)sender).Text, f);
    }
    ((Label)sender).Font = f;
}
```

Result - Winforms:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
private void Textbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{            
    textbox.FontSize = 24;
    textbox.UpdateLayout();

    ScrollViewer sv = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(textbox);

    if (sv != null)
    {
        Visibility VerticalScrollbarVisibility = sv.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility;
        if (VerticalScrollbarVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            while (VerticalScrollbarVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                textbox.FontSize = textbox.FontSize - 1;
                textbox.UpdateLayout();
                VerticalScrollbarVisibility = sv.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility;
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: It's definitely less code than the `Style`. Nice work.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to know the actual font size, you can modify the control template for a `TextBox`, adding a `ViewBox`, to do it all without any code.

The `ViewBox` automatically resizes its content so that it fits within the bounds of the parent.

If you only want to apply this to a subset of `TextBox` instances, change the `Style` `x:Key` to something like `x:Key="ResizingTextBox"`, and apply it to specific control by setting their `style` attribute.

[image: Demo GIF]
[image: Resizes with typing too!]

I used the following `Style` (note the `ViewBox`):

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                        <Border
                            Name="Border"
                            Padding="2"
                            Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="2">
                            <Viewbox>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Margin="0" />
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

It will also require the following resources defined somewhere:

```
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#FFF" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#CCC" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#FFF" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#CCC" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#FFF" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#EEE" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalLightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#FFF" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#EEE" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#FFF" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#AAA" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#BBB" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="#EEE" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.9" Color="#EEE" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#FFF" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#EEE" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD" />

    <!--  Border Brushes  -->

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#CCC" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#444" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#CCC" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#444" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DefaultedBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#777" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#000" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#444" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#888" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#888" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />

    <!--  Miscellaneous Brushes  -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444" />
```

The basic templates and resources were taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

This is the complete XAML, all in one place as a demo:

```
<Window
    x:Class="FontTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FontTest"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#FFF" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#CCC" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#FFF" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#CCC" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#FFF" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#EEE" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalLightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#FFF" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#EEE" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#FFF" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#AAA" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#BBB" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="#EEE" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.9" Color="#EEE" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#FFF" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#EEE" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD" />

        <!--  Border Brushes  -->

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#CCC" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#444" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#CCC" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#444" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DefaultedBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#777" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#000" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#444" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#888" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#888" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />

        <!--  Miscellaneous Brushes  -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightColorBrush" Color="#DDD" />
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                        <Border
                            Name="Border"
                            Padding="2"
                            Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="2">
                            <Viewbox>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Margin="0" />
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox
            x:Name="textbox_principal"
            Padding="0,5,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            CaretBrush="Black"
            FontSize="24"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Foreground="Black"
            SelectionBrush="#FF54FF50"
            Text="Texto"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

Multi-line seems to be working ok also.  You just have to embed the newline character with `&#x0a;`, like this:

```
Text="This is line 1&#x0a;This is line 2!"
```

It even works as you type if you add `AcceptsReturn="True"`.

[image]

Comment: Code xaml works vertically? I do not want in a row alone, I want to jump line to vertical. Sorry my english, I'm better

Comment: Please, look at the photo. https://s10.postimg.org/gygo2jv21/WPF1_2018-02-21_22-35-38.jpg

Comment: The photo is normal, let's say it has a large text.

Comment: The text box does not change the size, it is always fixed, I just need to decrease the font size. If you do not understand, I can explain more.

Comment: The `TextBox` its self is only changing size in the top GIF that I posted. That was just to show it working at any scale.  The 2nd GIF is a fixed size, and only the content within it is changing as the text changes. I'll investigate what can be done with multi-line.

Comment: I added some notes about multi-line handling at the bottom of my answer.  It seems to work just fine, as long as you manually place the line-breaks. Which seems like the behavior you would want with a dynamically changing fill like this.

Comment: I see what you are saying now about the size of the control changing.  That's purely an artifact of me not having the size fixed when I created the gufs.  If you take my code and add your height and width back in, it all works exactly as I think you want it to.

Comment: I've updated the last image to better show what it looks like when the textbox is a fixed size.

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle a string like you just posted.  If you are adjusting the font size, how can it tell if it should make the font very small and fit it all on one line, or keep the font larger and wrap every character?  Both of those options would meet the criteria of dynamically adjusting the font size to fin the characters.  I think the only way to accurately handle wrapped text is if the line breaks are explicitly coded in to the string.

Comment: not in a line, textbox moves the words down. If the textbox does not fit in the end, I want it to decrease.

Comment: The `textbox` already plays the next line automatically, I just want to decrease the font size when it does not fit all the letters.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but think about this.  If the font is *super* small, the entire text will fit on one single line.  It can always make the font smaller.  How does it know when it should wrap the line instead of decreasing the font size?

Comment: I edited post, please look at `label1_TextChanged` this code works on` winforms`, the problem is knowing how to do in WPF.

Comment: It already produces that exact result if you take away the height and width of the textbox, and use the specified string. See: https://imgur.com/a/Iie77

Comment: Again, I understand that part. But you are missing what would happen if you set the font size to `.00001`.  The entire text would all fit on one line.  That's what I meant earlier when I said that the font size can *always* get small enough to fit on a single line.

Comment: The textbox is characterized by the fixed width and when it informs a large number of characters it (textbox) automatically breaks the line. The problem is when I have a very large text with several lines and in this case a vertical scroolbar appears. It is at this point that I want to interfere by decreasing the font size so that all text fits within the textbox.

Comment: I see now.  You could get a reference to the `ScrollViewer` inside the `TextBox` and make the font size one step smaller until there are no more scrollbars.  I don't have time right now to code that up, but I think it should work.

Comment: Bradley Uffner Please see my answer. I found the solution.